# A probability question in a game

Tags: probability

So I am playing a game with my friends and we had an argument about the probability of us being oponnents.

So the rules are those:

There are 6 players. Out of these players 4 of us are friends. These players are randomly split in a group of 4 "good guys" and 2 "bad guys". What is the probability that the 4 friends are the good guys?
We are searching for the probability that all of us(the 4 friends) are good ones.

The number we had concluded is 16/81 which does not seem right at all.
I am curious about the approach of this problem, so any insight would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Please _edit it_ to show us the complete solution for a small example: say $3$ players, $2$ friends and $1$ bad one. Write down all the cases and count the ones in which the friends are all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question, it seems like out of the 6 people, you mark 2 of the people as bad, with the remaining 4 are good, and you want to calculate the probability that all 4 friends are good.

The way to do this (given random selection of the bad people) is to consider the fact that there's $\binom{6 - 4}{2} = \binom{2}{2}$ ways to pick the bad guys and have it not consist of any of the 4 friends, out of a total of $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose the bad guys with no restrictions.

This means that the probability is $\frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}} = \frac{1}{15}$

Answer (score 3):

There are $\binom 62$ equally likely ways to choose two “bad” guys out of six players, but only one of them picks the two strangers to be bad, so the probability you’re looking for is $1/\binom62$.